# the word to describes "open" or "close" words

Tags: word-usage

I want to know if there is exist the word to group two words

> open

> close

I searched but I didn't see the word.

Comment: Do you mean "opposite"?

Comment: Or *antonyms*, if you want a fancier term for *opposites*.

Comment: Or do you mean "is there one word that describes both *open* and *close*"?

Comment: [correction: I want to know if there is a word that means grouping words that are opposites or antonyms.]

Comment: @stangdon, yes, I need the word that describes both open and close

Comment: I'm not sure there is such a word.  I guess you could say that either to open or close the door is to *operate* the door or *manipulate* the door, but both of those seem very "artificial" to me.

Answer (score 1):

*Antonyms* are words that have opposite meanings: *fast* and *slow* or *hot* and *cold*, for example. It would also apply to your example of *open* and *close* whether you use them as adjectives or verbs.

*Opposites* is a broader term that could be used to refer to pairs of words, but it can also refer to the things themselves. For example, wins and losses are opposites. The words *win* and *lose* are antonyms (and also opposites).